# How to access scala string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

so I am using Java Play framework.
  In my view part, I pass in the variable from Java back end as string. Then I want to store that string in javascript in the view part, how can I do that?
code:

[image]

And it seems like output doesn't recognize the @message, so it shows up nothing.
The return type from Java side is String.
So JavaScript string and scala string are different? And what's the correct syntax?

Comment: This is a different question, it's not about php, it's scala and javascript, please reopen the question, thanks.

Comment: This is exactly the same question, just with different syntax. @message is a string, so when you use it in javascript you have to quote it: `var output = "@message";`

Comment: It's not correct, I just tried it...I mean how to pass string from scala to javascript on Java play template,  same string type. I cannot find answer online.